# x86 dissasembler that shows instruction extensions needed

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, instruction-set, micro-architecture

I need to check the minimal set of x86 instruction extensions needed to execute a given binary object (not a general binary, but the output of `gcc -c somefile.s`). Doing it by hand is time consuming and error prone. I am looking for an automated process.

What I need is some binary that given a binary object as input returns an `objdump`-like output augmented with x86 instruction extensions. Something like the following example:

```
$ objdump-extended -d someobject.o
...
66 41 0f 38 00 c0    SSSE3    pshufb %xmm8,%xmm0
66 0f 6f d8          SSE2     movdqa %xmm0,%xmm3
66 0f fe 00          SSE2     paddd  (%rax),%xmm0
0f 38 cb d1          SHANI    sha256rnds2 %xmm0,%xmm1,%xmm2
...
Extensions used: SSE2, SSSE3, SHANI, ...
```

Is there a similar tool available?

Comment: Note that static analysis can't tell you if an instruction present in the binary will actually *execute*.  It's not rare for optimized programs to  do dynamic dispatching, e.g. setting function pointers based on CPUID.  e.g. libx264 does this.  Even glibc does this!  You'll find AVX2 and AVX512 instructions in most Linux distro's builds of glibc, but it still works on baseline x86-64.  So while this tool could be useful, it won't directly tell you the minimum set of extensions to execute a binary.

Comment: @PeterCordes Its application will be for developing and debugging hand optimized assembly code. I will have complete control of which kind of binary objects I feed on it, so i don't need an infallible general purpose tool able to dial with fancy fat binaries or any kind of function multi versioning.

Comment: Yes, such a tool can be useful for checking that an AVX1+FMA function doesn't use any AVX2 instructions.  For hand-written asm, another option is to have your assembler check feature levels for you.  x264 has a comprehensive set of NASM macros that enable this, letting you declare on a per-function basis what level of instruction-set you're targeting.  It's GPLed I think, so check it out.

Comment: Or YASM lets you do `CPU EM64T SSE4.1` to enable SSE4.1 and x86-64 instructions, catching use of other instructions at assemble time. 
 https://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/manual.html#arch-x86-cpu.  (But YASM doesn't support AVX512).

Comment: The other common way to test this stuff is inside something like SDE, which lets you simulate a machine with AVX1 but not AVX2 for example, even on a machine with AVX2.  [Disabling AVX2 in CPU for testing purposes](//stackoverflow.com/q/55762372).  But that depends on running with test inputs that give 100% coverage of the instructions in your program.

Comment: @PeterCordes Can GNU Assembler be instructed to limit allowed opcodes? I need something that works with `gcc`. Switching the assembler is not an option.

Comment: GAS does document a `-march=CPU[+EXTENSION]` in its man page.  I think from gcc, you'd use `gcc -Wa,-march=znver1+fma` or something to pass on that option to the assembler.  Or with clang, I think the built-in assembler might do that normally for `clang -mssse3` or whatever.  Try it, and consider posting a separate self-answered Q&A if there isn't one on SO already.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest and most reliable option is the one @PeterCordes mentions: using the assembler command line options to limit the set of available instructions.

If you need a compile-time warning/error when using non allowed instructions extensions with `gas` through `gcc` the following snippet illustrates an example allowing only generic x86_64 instructions plus SSSE3 and SHANI extensions; anything else will report an error:

```
$ gcc -c -Wa,-march=generic64+ssse3+sha somefile.s
```

For already compiled binary objects I hacked a simple script that extends `objdump` output with per instruction extension with the help of the excellent tool [Zydis](https://github.com/zyantific/zydis):

```
#!/bin/bash

REGEX='^([0-9a-f]+)\s+<(.*)>\s+([0-9a-f][0-9a-f]( [0-9a-f][0-9a-f])*)\s+(.*?)$'
EXTS=

while read -r LINE ; do
  if [[ $LINE =~ $REGEX ]] ; then
    ADDR=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    LABEL=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    HEX=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    INSTR=${BASH_REMATCH[5]}
    EXT=$(ZydisInfo -64 $HEX | grep '    ISA-EXT:' | cut -d ' ' -f 6)
    [[ " $EXTS " != *" $EXT "* ]] && EXTS="$EXTS $EXT"
    echo -e "$LABEL\t$EXT\t$INSTR"
  fi
done < <(objdump --disassemble --wide --prefix-addresses --show-raw-insn "$1")

echo "Extensions:$EXTS"
```

**NOTE:** The previous code makes no attempt to check for errors or unexpected states. Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Intel's [X86 Encoder Decoder (XED)](https://intelxed.github.io/) to obtain a similar output.

Instructions:

```
git clone https://github.com/intelxed/xed.git xed
git clone https://github.com/intelxed/mbuild.git mbuild
cd xed
./mfile.py examples

obj/wkit/examples/obj/xed -A -i someobject.o
```

This produces the following output:

```
...
XDIS 0: SSE       SSSE3      66410F3800C0             pshufb %xmm8, %xmm0
XDIS 6: DATAXFER  SSE2       660F6FD8                 movdqa %xmm0, %xmm3
XDIS a: SSE       SSE2       660FFE00                 padddx  (%rax), %xmm0
XDIS e: SHA       SHA        0F38CBD1                 sha256rnds2 %xmm1, %xmm2
...
```

If you prefer Intel syntax, you can omit the `-A` parameter.